# R / Sweave: Prefixing and figure file naming

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am new to `R` and much newer to `Sweave` and I am experimenting with graphics. Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}  %%%%%%
\SweaveOpts{eps=true}
\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
test.frame<-data.frame(year=8:11, value= c(12050,15292,23907,33991))
@

\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=Evolution}
<<label=amount,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
postscript('doudou.eps',
            width=6, height=7,
            colormodel="cmyk",
            family = "ComputerModern")
with(test.frame,plot(year, value))
dev.off()
@

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,angle=90]{doudou.eps}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`What I want to do above?`

To have manual control over the `EPS` file that I am inserting so that I can have the `\includegraphics`command in the `Sweave` file itself.

And I am trying to give a proper file name to the figure: with prefix `Evolution` and label `amount` such that the `EPS` figure produced will be named `Evolution-amount.eps`.

`What is going wrong?`

As you can see, I am inserting a file name in the `R` `postscript` option i.e. `doudou.eps` . If I don't do this a file named `Rplots.ps` is created by `R`.

So my code is well ignoring the prefix and label that I want to give to my figure file.

And I am explicitly asking later on by `\includegraphics` to put `doudou.eps`.

`How I want it to be?`

To be able to have prefix and label as I mentioned above in the figure file name, while I still have manual control over the `\includegraphics` command in the `Sweave` file. Is this possible?

`What is the use of this?`

Say I am writing a paper and I have figures in different sections. So it would be nice to have something like:

```
\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=Paper2}

<<label=section2,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
```

and for example I specify in the `postscript` option: `model.eps`.

Then the figure would be named `Paper2-section2.model.eps` for example. Is that feasible?

And I would need to put this name somehow manually ?? in the `\includegraphics` command that follows.

Thanks a lot...

---

Update: 09 dec 2011.

A close solution with the help of cbeleites is:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Sweave} %%%%%%
\SweaveOpts{eps=TRUE}



\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
test.frame<-data.frame(year=8:11, value= c(12050,15292,23907,33991))
@

\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=Paper2}

<<label=section2, echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
ps.options ( width=6, height=7, colormodel="cmyk", family = "ComputerModern")
@


<<label=section2, fig=TRUE, include = TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
with(test.frame,plot(year, value))
@

\end{document}
```

On compilation I get the EPS and PDF files named Paper2-section2. This is as close as we can get I think.

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question in the question body.  This gets very confusing.  Each question on SO should stand by itself as a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need  to use a figure chunk.

```
    <<fig=TRUE, include = FALSE>>=
    with(test.frame,plot(year, value))
    @
```

- You can pass more options to the figure chunk, such as width and height.
- for more advanced options, use R's postscript options:

  ```
  <<>>=
  ps.options (colormodel="cmyk", family = "ComputerModern")
  @
  ```
- if the options apply only to one figure, you'd probably be easier off without figure chunk and with manual `\includegraphics`. You could give the filename to the ps file as if it was produced by a Sweave figure chunk, though.
- If the only reason for `\includegraphics` is that you want to control its options, have a look at graphicx' `Gin`:

  ```
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  <<fig=TRUE>>=
  with(test.frame,plot(year, value))
  @
  \end{center}
  \end{figure}
  ```

I thought Gin would work with the rotation as well, but it doesn't. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31013 for explanation and possible solution. However, if the rotation is only because the figures appear sideways (as opposed to you wanting them to be sideways) this may be solved with correct ps settings in R (`RSiteSearch ()` and `? postscript` should help).

Comment: @ cbeleites Thanks. When you do that, then we are completely ignoring the postscript options such as the font family of Computer Modern and so on.

Comment: @ yCalleecgaran: (no time to try actually, but) have a look at the manual. There's the possibility to use hooks which may help you in combination with `ps.options`. Or, also according to the manual, you could set up your own graphics device definintion.

Comment: @ cbeleites Thanks for referring me to the manual. That said, the post does not represent a big problem. I can always write the file name manually.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Had a bit of time to actually try things. `ps.options` works for me. Obviously before the figure chunk.

Comment: @ cbeleites Thanks for your efforts. I have updated the post with your suggestions and accepted your solution also. And 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: thanks. I also often find it tricky to know which such options should be changed what way - options, SweaveOpts, hook function, ... somewhere entirely else?